# selecting 2 specific values from 2 different tables, and insering them to a third table only if a condition

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, T1 T2 and T3.

- T1 has 2 columns: `t1_id`, `t1_country`
- T2 also has 2 columns: `t2_id`, `t2_country`

I need to insert into T3 the tuple `(t1_id,t2_id)` (t1_id and t2_id are specific and given) BUT only if `t1_country = t2_country`.

I tried to create 3 queries:

1. selecting from T1 the specific t1_id
2. selecting from T2 t2_id AND country==the country i've found in the previous query. (by using SELECT... WHERE(..AND..))
3. inserting the 2 given id's to the 3rd table

   ```
       pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id , country FROM T1"+
               " where id= ?  ");
       pstmt.setInt(1,t1_id);
       ResultSet results = pstmt.executeQuery();

       pstmt2 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM T2"+
               " where id= ? AND country=?  ");
       pstmt2.setInt(1,t2_id);
       pstmt2.setString(2,results.getString("country"));
       ResultSet results2 = pstmt2.executeQuery();

       pstmt3 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO T3" +
               " VALUES (?, ?)");
       pstmt3.setInt(1, results.getInt("id"));
       pstmt3.setInt(2, results2.getInt("id"));
       pstmt3.executeQuery();
   ```

Comment: What's the issue? What errors are you receiving? What programming language are you using to execute these queries?

Comment: You don't need three queries, a single `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`  will do and is most probably a lot more efficient as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could do with just a query

```
  insert into T3 
  select  t1.id, t2.id
  from  t1 
  inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id  
     and t2.country = t1.country 
     and t1.id  = ?
```